# Is there support for postgres as external storage?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am trying to configure postgres DB as external storage (persistent store) for Ignite-GridGain cache.

Here is my XML configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd              http://www.springframework.org/schema/util              http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <!-- Data source bean -->
    <bean class="com.postgresql.cj.jdbc.postgresqlDataSource" id="postgresqlDataSource">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ignite_test"/>
        <property name="user" value="USERNAME"/>
        <property name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
    </bean>
```

I am getting below error. Can someone help with postgres configuration with Ignite-GridGain?

Cannot find class [com.postgresql.cj.jdbc.postgresqlDataSource] for bean with name 'postgresqlDataSource' defined in URL

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your JDBC driver is is Ignite's classpath. Normally you do that by adding it to your `USER_LIBS` environment variable.

```
export USER_LIBS=/PATH/TO/postgress.jar
$IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignite.sh myconfig.xml
```